# fpscala: Error with pattern matching in sequence() function

Tags: scala

I'm following the book Functional Programming in Scala and working on problem 4.4.

I'm getting an error even though I copy and pasted the code from the answer key and I am not sure how to resolve.

```
  def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = a match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h.flatMap(hh => sequence(t).map(hh :: _))
  }
```

Error:

```
Error:(45, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[A]
 required: List[Option[?A1]] where type ?A1 <: A (this is a GADT skolem)
    case h :: t => h.flatMap(hh => sequence(t).map(hh :: _))
```

What seems to be the issue?

EDIT: It seems that the issue is because I have `List` defined in a different file under the same directory. How can I make this file use `scala.List` instead of my defined `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide only your custom `List` class:

```
import custom.{List => _}
```

hide your `List` implementation while importing everything else from the `custom` package:

```
import custom.{List => _, _}
```

or you can do vice versa - give a class a new name (or alias) when you import it:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{List => RenamedList}
```

and reference `scala.List` with `RenamedList`